# PHP Mailer slow to send message

Tags: php, html

(Please be patient with me, PHP wasn't in the job description when I signed on to this job.) 
(I'm also not responsible for the tables in the HTML.)

Based on the email I got, the "issue" that the php mailer is having, is that it takes about 20 minutes to receive an email after initially submitting the form.

duramatic.com

Here's my tutorial-written code:

```
<?php

/* These are the variable that tell the subject of the email and where the email will be     sent.*/

$emailSubject = 'Quote Request';
$mailto = 'sales@duramatic.com';

/* These will gather what the user has typed into the fieled. */

$nameField = $_POST['name'];
$titleField= $_POST['title'];
$companyField = $_POST['company'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$commentsField = $_POST['comments'];

/* This takes the information and lines it up the way you want it to be sent in the email. */

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $nameField <br>
Title: $titleField <br>
Company: $companyField <br>
Phone: $phoneField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Comments: $commentsField <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; // This takes the email and displays it as who this email is from.
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; // This tells the server to turn the coding into the text.
$success = mail($mailto, $emailSubject, $body, $headers); // This tells the server what to send.
/* REsults */

$theResults = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
```

And here's where this is referenced in HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="form_mailer.php" ><table class="quote">                      <tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a code issue? Could be a server issue. Either your host's server or your email provider's.

Comment: If you open up one of the emails, and look at the headers, you'll see a few `Received-From: ` headers, which track the email's progress through various servers. They also include a timestamp, which means that you can see how long it took for each server to process them. I'd start off there, rather than with your PHP code.

Comment: Don't blame the code, blame the ISP/web host and potential high volumes of traffic. (Some ISP's send out thousands and thousands an hour). Yours may be in a queue or have a quota set. I've seen that happen lately, as a matter 'o **fact**. Contact your ISP/web hosting company.

Comment: So look at your mail server's logs, on both the sending and receiving sides. That'll tell you where the delay is. If it's a **CONSTANT** 20 minutes, for every mail, then perhaps your receiving server is greylisting the sending server.

Comment: **Quantum** computers aren't on the market yet ;-)